# How to return value as checked check_boxes in active admin? [ruby]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm currently having a hard time and try to figure it out on how to return array value as checked box in active_admin gem on ruby on edit form.

it successfully edit the value and updated the array which currently using a has many and belongs to table relationship.but everytime it return to the page, the checkboxes return with no checked boxes.

here are the codes.

```
f.input   :additional_toppings, collection: AdditionalTopping.all.map{|t| [t.name, t.id]}, 
as: :check_boxes, filter: food.additional_toppings
```

i did try to use `:checked` but with no success.

and also i want to know if its possible for the active admin to display read only value some say to use `:disabled => true` but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found out the answer and it's particularly simple. (Finally for days)

All I gotta do is just remove the collection, as well change the filter into checked.
I also changed the `additional_toppings` into `additional_topping_ids` to return the array and I also add the `accessible` attribute.

Here are the codes:

```
f.input :additional_toppings, as: :check_boxes, checked: food.additional_topping_ids
```

---

```
attr_accessible :name, :price, :quantity, :picture, :category_id, :info , :favourite, :weekly, :unlimited, :toppings, :tag_list, :additional_topping_ids

has_many :categorizations
has_many :additional_toppings, :through => :categorizations
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the removal for collection! I was wondering why my checkboxes aren't highlighted too.

Comment: This helped me alot. I've been searching for the same thing and didn't know about ```checked``` rather than ```collection```. thanks!